# PTAM on iPhone (AR)

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I want to implement PTAM(Parallel Tracking and Mapping) system in iPhone.

like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBI5HwitBX4

Does anyone know open-source project of PTAM or a sample code?

Answer (score 3):

If you click the link in that YouTube video's description, there's a page with the source code for the demo. http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/PTAM/

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, checkout this repo [iPTAM](https://github.com/twerdster/iPTAM) on Github.

Though the repo is kind of outdated for now, it's a good starting point, the author basically ported the main part of PTAM to iOS.